# Javascript regex to replace HTML FONT Tag

Tags: javascript

I have a html string like `<FONT id="test" face="Arial"><SPAN><P>This is some content...</P></SPAN></FONT>`. Now using javascript regex I want to remove the font tag with id test and the span tag with their associated closing tags.

So that the output becomes `<P>This is some content...</P>` .How to do this ?

Comment: do you need the <p> tags surrounding the text ?

Comment: Don't use regexes on HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454   JS is already perfectly capable of manipulating the DOM without any regexes at all.

Comment: yes..there may be some other tags also surrounding the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally agreed upon that using Regex to parse HTML is a bad idea. I would recommend you use jQuery to parse this into DOM elements and then manipulate it.

```
var content = $('<FONT id="test" face="Arial"><SPAN><P>This is some content...</P></SPAN></FONT>').find('span').children();
```

Or use (but I wouldn't recommend it) the DOM api itself:

```
var str = '<FONT id="test" face="Arial"><SPAN><P>This is some content...</P></SPAN></FONT>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var newStr = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(newStr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhRYX/

Comment: is there any way to achieve the same not using jquery,i.e using plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/hAPzQ/

script :

```
var testdom = document.getElementById('test');
var replacedom = testdom.childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
testdom.parentNode.replaceChild(replacedom,testdom);
```

`.replaceChild()` is cross-browser -> http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#nodemanipulation